# How do we update the parameters of an ellipse patch in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ellipse

I'm new to Matplotlib and I'm trying to update an ellipse patch using a `for` loop.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
fig, plts = plt.subplots(1,1)
cE = Ellipse(xy, w, h, theta)
plts.add_patch(cE)
plt.show()
for i in range(0, 10):
    xy_update, theta_update = some_function(i)
    cE.<?> = xy_update
    cE.<?> = theta_update
    canvas.draw()
```

I'm looking for the correct way `<?>` to update Ellipse patch parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`Ellipse.set_center`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.1.0/lib/matplotlib/patches.py#L1508) to set the `xy` coordinates of the ellipse center.

While that has a `setter`, the rotation of the ellipse which is given by the `angle` option doesn't.

You may set [`angle`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.1.0/lib/matplotlib/patches.py#L1478) property on the ellipse instance then set `xy`.

```py
cE.angle = theta_update
cE.set_center(xy_update)
```

You can also make a new instance of the Ellipse using [`Ellipse.update_from`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.1.0/lib/matplotlib/patches.py#L180) and update the old one from it

```py
cE.update_from(Ellipse(xy_update, w, h, theta_update))
```

Comment: ... and just as always a solution has to be found on the 15th link of page 2 after the question is *just posted* by me. Haha, I was going to stop by to delete my question but you got to it before I did. Thanks Oluwafemi. I think there are special properties for `cE.center`, `cE.angle`, `cE.width` etc.

Comment: Glad you found an answer. Yes, you're correct that there are special properties for `Ellipse`. The ellipse _center_ however is a private one so one has to go through the public setter to set it